# Best way to change tkinter widgets real time

Tags: python, tkinter

I want GUI widgets to change as i choose different radio buttons, I have managed this, but there has to be better ways to do it. Right now i have 1 function for 1 radio button, I want to have 1 function for all 3 radio buttons. I have tried to use the 'noo' variable, but after I make it a global variable I can't seem to use the '.get' function on it, which should output values 1-3.

```
def skjerm_switch():
    e3.configure(state=DISABLED)
    e2.configure(state=NORMAL)
    e1.configure(state=NORMAL)
    l_skjermer.configure(text="Skjerm")
    l_pc.configure(text="Ident")
    l_hub.configure(text="")


def pc_switch():
    e3.configure(state=NORMAL)
    e2.configure(state=NORMAL)
    e1.configure(state=NORMAL)
    l_skjermer.configure(text="PC")
    l_pc.configure(text="Ident")
    l_hub.configure(text="Kommentar")


def hub_switch():
    e3.configure(state=DISABLED)
    e2.configure(state=NORMAL)
    e1.configure(state=NORMAL)
    l_skjermer.configure(text="HUB")
    l_pc.configure(text="Ident")
    l_hub.configure(text="")
```

The reason for this GUI to be in a function is because this function is started by a button in another window.

```
def new_record():
    addition = tkinter.Tk()
    addition.title("Legg til")
    addition.geometry("500x300+1000+250")
    addition.resizable(0, 0)
    noo = IntVar()
    global e3
    global e2
    global e1
    global l_skjermer
    global l_pc
    global l_hub

    c1 = Radiobutton(addition, text="Skjermer", width=10, variable=noo, value=1,         
    command=skjerm_switch)
    c1.select()
    c2 = Radiobutton(addition, text="Pcer", width=10, variable=noo, value=2, command=pc_switch)
    c3 = Radiobutton(addition, text="Hubs", width=10, variable=noo, value=3, command=hub_switch)
    e1 = Entry(addition, width=20)
    e2 = Entry(addition, width=20)
    e3 = Entry(addition, width=25, state=DISABLED)
    l_skjermer = Label(addition, text="Skjerm")
    l_pc = Label(addition, text="Ident")
    l_hub = Label(addition)

    l_skjermer.place(x=80, y=100)
    l_pc.place(x=220, y=100)
    l_hub.place(x=360, y=100)
    c1.place(x=100, y=30)
    c2.place(x=185, y=30)
    c3.place(x=270, y=30)
    e1.place(x=40, y=75)
    e2.place(x=175, y=75)
    e3.place(x=310, y=75)
    addition.mainloop()
```

I'll throw in a picture of the GUI for a better understanding. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFnyK.jpg)

Comment: Calling `noo.get()` in the switch function works for me. Maybe your `global noo` was in the wrong place. In your posted code, it needs to be in the `new_record` function _before_ `noo = IntVar()`.

Comment: @Wups I have tried that as well, but I only get the number 0. I don't know why it's not giving me 1,2 or 3.

Comment: I think you have another instance of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel` instead inside `new_record()`.  Or `noo = IntVar(master=addition)`.

Comment: Thank you @acw1668. 'IntVar(master=addition)' worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually never recommended to use more than one instance of `Tk()`, usage of such might be the problem here, that the `IntVar()` doesnt know which parent to work for.

**Method 1:**
Either replace the `Tk()` with `Toplevel()` (recommended)

**Method 2:**
...or use the master argument for the `IntVar()` like, `oo = IntVar(master=addition)`.

The latter is a way around the issue, but still later on you might get different errors if you have multiple instance of `Tk()`.

Hope this cleared your doubts, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers